# The getElementByID isnt showing the value

Tags: javascript, html

PLeaseHelp. it wont show the Value, even for form authentication, to get username & password values,I was trying the same methods.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=<device-width>,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="result">Selected movie is </h1>

    <select id="movie" onchange="showmovie()">
        <option value="Spiderman">Spiderman</option>
        <option value="Spiderman2">Spiderman2</option>
        <option value="Spiderman3">Spiderman3</option>

    </select>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    var movie = document.getElementById("movie").value

    function showmovie(){
        alert("Changed")
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Movie chosen is"+movie
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `<script>` elements have to be a child of `<head>` or `<body>`

Comment: You're grabbing the **value** of the `select` when the page loads, not when your function runs. Instead, grab the select itself (remove the `.value`) and then use it in the function (by adding the `.value` on `movie`). Oh! And what @Andreas said, though I've never seen a browser actually enforce that restriction.

Comment: Side note: I'd strongly recommend using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) over `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this function showmovie

```
 <script>
    function showmovie() {
        //Selected option
        var selectedMovie = document.getElementById("movie").value;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Movie chosen is " + selectedMovie;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is because of the line  `var movie = document.getElementById("movie").value` being executed just one time at the beginning (you could verify that adding `console.log(movie);` just after the movie variable declaration)

(`movie` stores then the value 'Spierdaman') and it never executes again with the calls for `showmovie()` function, so you could just move the `movie` declaration line above inside the function so it executes each time the action occurs and then having the good values.

Other details : To have a compliant code i suggest moving the script bloc to part just before  and dont forget to add semicolons ';' at the end of each line ! + Better approach would be to use an eventListener as suggested by @T.J. Crowder in comments section above